# is admob banner show before publish application?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I add all codes of admob into my project and when I test it by admob test code , it work well . but
if i try to add my own appID and UnitID , my Ads don't shows 
//
I think before publishing App it doesnt show 
am I right or I have some other problem ?

**java.class**

[image: picture of java.class]

**layout.xml**

[image: picture of layout.xml]

**Manifest.xml**

[image: picture of ManuFast]

I don't think that I have code problem
I think it is because of that my app in not published
please answer me thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or links to images, as images are not searchable and this makes it hard to understand your question once the image target gets removed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surely shows the advertisement even without publishing app. Make sure you also sign in to google adsense with the same account you signed in to admob.

Comment: thank you I try to have aquant google adsense  and check it again

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your payment account is setup with admob.

Also for testing purpose, you need to add your device as text device.

**Like This**

```
smartAd = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.smartAd);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("709D9B***********629841A46A05C6B").build();
    smartAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

You can find your device number in logs.
Hope this will help.

Comment: no i don't set my payment account in admob
thank you I try your solution  and check it again

Comment: Sure Do it and let me know if it helped